# Delete Job Scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I have job key in database and i want to delete that job key.

> Issue- I am using `scheduler.deleteJob  //(Job name is in String)`

I want to convert `Job name` to `Job Key`

Anyone if you can help! help me. Please provide me a solution.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assump that you want to start/stop a scheduled job by it's key (group, name).
Here is how i did it in my project:

**start new schedule**

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(YourJob.class)
        .withIdentity("your-job-name", "your-job-group")
        .build();
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("your-trigger-name", "your-trigger-group")
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 * * ? *"))
        .startNow()
        .build();
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
scheduler.start();
```

**stop a schedule and job**

```
scheduler.deleteJob(new JobKey("your-job-name", "your-job-group"));
TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey("your-trigger-name", "your-trigger-group");
scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey);
```